# Detect segmentation fault in Qt unit test

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qttest

Is it possible to detect segmentation faults (`SIGSEGV`) within the Qt test library?

Within my `testXXX()` method, a segmentation fault is thrown which causes a core file to be written. The funny thing about that is that the `QTest::qExec()` method returns 0 from the method in question.

Even after the segmentation fault the Qt test framework **keeps on running with the same PID!!!***

I've tried to set up a signal handler using the `sigaction()` system call, but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions welcome and appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that you actually have SIGSEGV?

Comment: I can see it at the top of the stack trace in GDB.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I found the underlying cause. Qt sets its own signal handler within `QTest::qExec()`, which will overwrite anything that has been set prior to that. I found that out while digging in `src/testlib/qtestcase.cpp`. There's a class `FatalSignalHandler` that will assign signal handlers for a bunch of signals in its constructor.

Comment: Actually that is the answer, is it ok if I answer my own question?